# Newly Added Item is added to the collection but not in the treeViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView. I have a contextMenu defined for the TreeViewItems.

When I right click on any TreeViewItem, I get a ContextMenu which has an option to add a new TreeViewItem under the Item on which user Right-clicked.

Here is my code:

```
private void AddContextMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem treeViewItem = null;

    foreach (TreeViewItem tvItem in StaticHelpers.FindVisualChildren<TreeViewItem>(cityTreeView))
    {
        if (tvItem.Header == ServiceLocator.Instance.SelectedCity)
        {
            treeViewItem = tvItem;
            break;
        }
    }

    AddNewCity(ServiceLocator.Instance.SelectedCity);

    treeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;

    City newlyAddedCity = getNewlyAddedCity(ServiceLocator.Instance.Cities);

    foreach (TreeViewItem tvItem in StaticHelpers.FindVisualChildren<TreeViewItem>(cityTreeView))
    {
        if (tvItem.Header == newlyAddedCity)
        {
            treeViewItem = tvItem;
            break;
        }
    }

    this.RenameContextMenu_Click(treeViewItem, e);
}
```

Now in the code above if I keep a breakpoint on last foreach loop, I can see that it loops through all the parent Items and those child Items whose parent's IsExpanded is set to true.

But I can also notice that when it loops through all the items, it does not get newlyAddedCity in the collection and as a result in second for loop tvItem.Header == newlyAddedCity never becomes true.

At last when the task is finished by computer I can see the newlyAddedCity in TreeView.

**Update:**

Here is my AddNewCity Method:

```
public static void AddNewCity(City parentCity)
{
    City lastAddedCity = ServiceLocator.Instance.Cities.Where(x => x.IsLastAdded == true).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
    lastAddedCity.IsLastAdded = false;

    City newCity = new City()
                    {
                        Id = lastAddedCity.Id + 1,
                        IsLastAdded = true,
                        Name = "New City"
                    };

    ServiceLocator.Instance.Cities.Where(x => x.Id == parentCity.Id).FirstOrDefault().Children.Add(newCity);
    CityMethods.SaveNew(parentCity.Id, "");
}
```

Comment: So, your issue is just you could not hit the breakpoint OR facing some issue adding object to treeView?

Comment: Yes the above code just does not hit the breakpoint. No, I am not facing any issues adding object to the treeView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeViewItem is an UI container which gets generated when it comes in View. In code you set IsExpanded to True but ***UI dispatcher didn't get time to do that processing for generating container because it's busy in executing click handler.***

---

In case you interested in seeing item generated, you need to give UI thread some time to process it before running last foreach loop.

***Invoke empty delegate on UI dispatcher with priority Render*** so that all delegates queued on UI dispatcher with priority higher or equal to Render gets time to execute. *(UI refresh on priority Render)*

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

*Just place this code before your last foreach loop and you will see breakpoint gets hit.*

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
foreach (TreeViewItem tvItem in StaticHelpers.FindVisualChildren<TreeViewItem>(cityTreeView))
{
    if (tvItem.Header == newlyAddedCity)
    {
        treeViewItem = tvItem;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the mvvm way would be to add a new item to the underlying collection and not to the treeview.

```
   public OberservableCollection<City> MyCollection {get;set;}

   this.MyCollection.Add(getNewlyAddedCity(ServiceLocator.Instance.Cities));
```

xaml

```
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"/>
```

Comment: I am doing exactly that. Look at my Update part in question.

Comment: i just see handling treeviewitem stuff directly without binding, but if it works for you then all is ok. my example has no codebehind at all

Comment: I need to use code-behind because I would like to add drag-drop, add, rename, delete, etc. facilities to my client.